# Modern English to Early Modern English

Tags: translation, early-modern-english

What will be a proper translation from modern english to Shakespearean english of this line:

> The Demon I have faced, is the Demon I have become.

Comment: This question would be improved by specifying what translations you've come up with and where your major concern lies.

Answer (score 4):

Shakespeare could have written this, except that he would have written "am become", not "have become".

Shakespeare didn't write in Old English, by the way; he wrote in Early Modern English.

Comment: Would he have had a comma? It's not right nowadays.

Comment: I dispute that. It is not required, but to claim that it is "not right" is a zombie rule. I can read it out with or without a pause, so I can write it with or without a comma. As for Shakespeare's punctuation - I think you'll find it was even more unregulated than his spelling.

Comment: @ColinFine It’s a bit more than “not required”. It’s a comma that, for no good reason, splits up a subject and its predicate, which commas do not usually do. Restrictive relative clauses as light as this one generally do not require commas in English, and pauses are absolutely atrocious as an only indicator of where to put commas. If pauses were the criterion, you might as well punctuate it as “The Demon, I have faced is the Demon, I have become” or “The Demon I have, faced is the Demon I have, become”.

Comment: @Janus: in the 18th and 19th centuries, writers used many more commas than they do today, often including ones that split the subject from the predicate. The publishers have removed most of them from today's editions, as they are now quite distracting to readers. For example, from Anne Brontë: *"I think the day I last mentioned, was a certain Saturday, the latest in the October of 1827".* I don't know about Shakespeare's commas.

Comment: "The dæmon I faced, I am now become" would be iambic pentameter, while maintaining the balance of the two clauses, and using a spelling of *demon* that Shakespeare used in "Henry V".

Comment: @Peter Certainly—and I would not be at all surprised to find the comma present in both Brontëan and Shakespearean writing. Colin’s dispute (which I disputed) was purely regarding Andrew’s in my opinion correct assertion that it wouldn’t be right in _current_ punctuation practices.